# How to get two chrome userscripts to use just one jQuery instance?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, userscripts

In my userscripts, I use this code to get jQuery and rest of my code injected and executed:

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
function readyJQuery() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //my rest code goes here
  })
}
addJQuery(readyJQuery)
```

This works perfectly. But when I have two scripts they both inject the jQuery part. The scripts need to be separate, because I don't know who wants to use which script or both scripts.

Can I prevent the second script from injecting jQuery and use the one from the first script?

When the second script directly starts with:

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
function readyJQuery() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //my rest code goes here
  })
}
addJQuery(readyJQuery)
```

I get the error Message in the console: `jQuery is undefined`.
How can I test if a different script already injected jQuery and then wait until it's ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your jQuery a unique identifier, check for that identifier, and only add jQuery if it is not found.  You'll also need to allow enough to time for the first jQuery to initialize.

Changing `addJQuery()` to the following, in both scripts, works in my tests:

```
function addJQuery (callback) {
    //--- Has jQuery already been added?
    var jqNode  = document.querySelector ("#myAddedJQ");
    if (jqNode) {
        FireCallback (callback);
    }
    else {
        //--- Wait a bit to be sure.
        setTimeout ( function() {
                var jqNode  = document.querySelector ("#myAddedJQ");
                if (jqNode) {
                    FireCallback (callback);
                }
                else {
                    var script  = document.createElement ("script");
                    script.id   = "myAddedJQ";
                    script.setAttribute (
                        "src",
                        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
                    );
                    script.addEventListener ('load', function () {
                        FireCallback (callback);
                    }, false);
                    document.body.appendChild (script);
                }
            }
            , 444
        );
    }

    function FireCallback (callback) {
        var script          = document.createElement ("script");
        script.textContent  = "                                         \
            if (typeof waitForJqDefined == 'undefined') {               \
                var waitForJqDefined    = setInterval ( function () {   \
                        if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {             \
                            clearInterval (waitForJqDefined);           \
        ";
        script.textContent += "\n(" + callback.toString() + ")();\n";
        script.textContent += "                                         \
                        }                                               \
                    },                                                  \
                    50                                                  \
                );                                                      \
            }                                                           \
            else {                                                      \
        ";
        script.textContent += "\n(" + callback.toString() + ")();\n";
        script.textContent += "                                         \
            }                                                           \
        ";
        document.body.appendChild (script);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before injecting the script to load jQuery - why don't you check to see if it already exists?

If you are worried about a race condition: both scripts trying to load it at the same time - you can narrow that race condition by setting a flag in the global scope and check that as well.  Doesn't remove the race condition, but may help.

```
if ( typeof jQueryLoading == 'undefined')
   var jQueryLoading = false;
if ( typeof jQuery == 'undefined' && jQueryLoading == false )
{
  jQueryLoading = true;
  //Load it yourself, then add scripts
}
else
{
  //No problems. Add your scripts
}
```

Comment: I don't think that one script can see the sandboxed scope of the other.

Comment: it appears he's still using jQuery from the global scope - or did I miss something - taking another look now

Comment: yeah - unless Im missing something fundamental here - jquery would still be added to the global scope when the script is added to the dom and executed.  the `noConflict()` just releasing the `$` var.  `window.jQuery` should still exist.  I think the `jQuery is undefined` error is from the race condition I mentioned.  A setTimeout / setInterval would work as in your answer.

Comment: I already tried this:
    function wait_for_jquery(attempts) {
      try {
        $ = window.jQuery || this.jQuery;
      } catch(err) {
        alert(err);
      }
      if ($ == null || typeof $ == "undefined") {
        if (attempts > 0) {
          console.log("Attempt:" + attempts);
          window.setTimeout(wait_for_jquery, 250, attempts-1);
        }
      } else {
        alert("jQuery ready");
      }
    }
But it didn worked. The complete site was loaded already. The first script working as intenden, while the second script was still testing and always got the undefined error.